# why sanity start failed to compile in my nextjs app?

Tags: next.js, compilation, package.json, sanity

as a beginner i'm trying to follow up  with a tutorial that uses sanity for backend , the problem is that when it come to the step to start sanity , so many errors are showing up here is the first one that i think is the major one that blocks the compilation

```
Error in ./schemas/schema.js (part:@sanity/base/schema)
Module build failed: Error: [BABEL]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ghars\tiktik-a
pp\sanity-backend\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js'. Please
verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry (While processing: C:\User
s\ghars\tiktik-app\sanity-backend\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-class-prop
erties\lib\index.js)
```

i've searched about this and i think that sanity have a problem when it comes to node version 17 that i'm using , is there any solution without passing back to node 16 ?

Comment: Probably not a direct solution to your problem, but Node.js 17.x reached end-of-life in June 2022. I'd highly recommend you move to either Node.js 16 (active LTS) or 18 (current).